# Porting windows socket program to Linux [ WSAAsyncSelect and CreateWindow]

Tags: linux, delphi, winsock, createwindow, wsaasyncselect

I am trying to port a legacy Delphi code in windows to Linux. But I am facing difficulty in finding out the equivalent of few windows functions in Linux. Currently I have a block of code that does socket operations using winsock, the outline of the code is as below(as I cant post the actual entire code due to security reason) . So any suggestion on how to achieve the same functionality in Linux(not necessarily for Delphi, but it can be in C/C++) would be of great help.

My understanding about the below code is that the thread creates a window and wait for the message WM_USER and later when the program creates a socket, program registers the socket to send the WM_USER message once it has any event among FD_READ or FD_WRITE or FD_ACCEPT or FD_CONNECT or FD_CLOSE. Once the socket has any of the event mentioned in the list, it send a WM_USER message and the window handler process this message. So my question here is how can I implement the similar functionality in Linux when I port the program to Linux?

```
int main()
{
...
 1. A thread is created and which executes the function thread_Function() shown below
....
....
 2. Now the program creates a TCP socket(TheSocket), sets few socket options and does the binding and invokes the WSAAsyncSelect() functionas follows on the socket

    if WSAAsyncSelect(TheSocket, WindowHandle, WM_USER,
    FD_READ or FD_WRITE or FD_ACCEPT or FD_CONNECT or FD_CLOSE)  



}

void thread_Function()
{
    WindowHandle := CreateWindow(
      name, name,  // class name, window name
      0, 0, 0, 0, 0,  // window style, x, y, width, hight
      0, 0,  // handle to parent and menu or child-window identifier
      HInstance,// handle to application instance
      nil); // pointer to window-creation data
    if WindowHandle = 0 then
      Print('Can''t create window handle: '+SysErrorMessage(GetLastError))
    else begin
      while GetMessage(Msg, 0, 0, 0) do begin
        if Msg.message = WM_USER then begin
                HandleSocketMessage()
        end
      end
    end
}
```

Comment: This https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/i/7.4?topic=programming-examples-socket-application-designs could help get you started.

Comment: What Delphi version do you have? Current versions can target Linux! Maybe it is easier and cheaper to buy a current license than making a complete rewrite!?

Comment: @DelphiCoder I am using 10.4 Sydney Architect version. And yes I can target Linux, but the existing code contains Winsock functions for socket and that is not supported in Linux. So I am trying to find the equivalent functions in Linux.

Comment: You could consider rewriting the code with portable network components like Indy. [`WSAAsyncSelect()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winsock/nf-winsock-wsaasyncselect) seems to be deprecated anyway.

Comment: My understanding is that the dummy window and message loop for it can simply be skipped (replaced with just a busy loop (repeat ... until False) or whatever event handling the replacement on Linux offers - the dummy window and message loop are just the way WSAAsyncSelect happens to pass its events to you). The remaining question is what to replace WSAAsyncSelect with. Something in System.Net.Socket might do.